# It's not a virus

Tags: articles, négation, de

A colleague just asked me about a file on my computer, and I answered him that the file is not a virus, but I'm doubting if I did it correctly.
Let's compare with the sentence "There are no viruses":

| English | Dutch | French |
| --- | --- | --- |
| There are no viruses | Er zijn geen virussen | Il n'y a pas **de** virus |
| It's not a virus | Het is geen virus | "Ce n'est pas **un** virus." OR "Ce n'est pas **de** virus." |

I went for the first choice, but I'm afraid it might be an anglicism.

Which one is right?

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is right. Orally, that would more likely be: ***C'est pas un virus*** while the first one would be ***Y'a pas d'virus***.

The second sentence ("*être pas de virus*") just doesn't work.

What would be possible:

> ***Ce ne sont pas des virus**.* (There are things, but they are not viruses.)

> *Ce n'est pas du virus.* (Colloquial, taking *virus* as uncountable.)

Comment: Do you have some "official" reference?

Comment: @Dominique you can check in any grammar how negation is formed. *C'est un virus.* -> *Ce n'est pas un virus.* However, *il y a* (=there is) is a somewhat special grammatical structure: *il y a* -> *il n'y a pas de*.

Comment: *Il n'y a pas un virus* is also possible but can be ambiguous (*pas un virus, mais trois !*) while *pas de virus* is not ambiguous.

Comment: How does “ce ne sont pas des virus” mean ‘there are things, but nothing like viruses’? Wouldn’t it just be ‘these aren’t viruses’?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It can be simply translated that way indeed but Isn't the meaning essentially identical? That sentence wasn't a translation but an explanation. I wanted to make clear that when you say *ce ne sont pas...*, you are talking about actual things so it it different from saying *il n'y a pas de...* where you are talking about an absence.

Comment: Ah, okay – I misunderstood, then. I would phrase that as ‘there are [some] things, but they’re not viruses’, since ‘nothing like’ means ‘completely dissimilar to’ (≈ _il y a bien des trucs, mais ils ne sont absolument pas comme des virus_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks, it was too strong indeed. I wanted to say something like *mais rien qui soit un virus*.

Comment: Obviously, "Y'a pas" should be "Il n'y a pas" :-)

Comment: @Dominique Ben non, j'ai écrit *orally*. Je fais référence à des personnes qui s'expriment oralement de manière naturelle, pas comme si elles lisaient un livre ou passaient au tableau, à l'école.